# Resource is a complex map type

Tags: android

Haven't been able to find anything online about this. When I run my app I get a ton of these errors (app doesn't crash). I assume whatever it is, it's causing some overhead. What is this error?

```
09-02 21:33:14.457 20085-20085/com.testing.litrans.app E/ans.app: Resource 7f030003 is a complex map type.
09-02 21:33:14.528 20085-20085/com.testing.litrans.app E/ans.app: Resource 7f030003 is a complex map type.
09-02 21:33:14.591 20085-20085/com.testing.litrans.app E/ans.app: Resource 7f030003 is a complex map type.
09-02 21:33:14.756 20085-20085/com.testing.litrans.app E/ans.app: Resource 7f030003 is a complex map type.
09-02 21:33:14.957 20085-20085/com.testing.litrans.app E/ans.app: Resource 7f030003 is a complex map type.
09-02 21:33:14.958 20085-20085/com.testing.litrans.app E/ans.app: Resource 7f030003 is a complex map type.
```

Comment: `Resource 7f030003`  - did you find that value (7f030003) in your `R.java` file? if so what is it?

Comment: @pskink Just took a look, it's `public static final int preloaded_fonts=0x7f030003;`

Comment: in what class ?

Comment: sorry, it's in the array class

Comment: so post the definition, do you have arrays.xml or something similar?

Comment: Any news ? I got the same message

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact problem you were having, but in my case I saw these errors when I was reading a string from resources, however the string was a [Quantity String](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals) so calling `resources.getString()` instead of `resources.getQuanityString()` was the culprit.